# Javascript and css syntax , how to define the 'px'

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

I have a very simple syntax issue that I cannot figure out. I have the following lines of code which is correct:

```
gridTemplateColumns: '100px 100px 100px',
height: Math.max(65, 200) + 'px',
```

Now I want to add the Math.max (x,x) in all three parameters of gridTemplateColumns: '100px 100px 100px.

The following are the ones that I tried but they are simply not correct:

```
gridTemplateColumns: Math.max(100, 50) Math.max(100, 50) Math.max(100, 50)+'px',
gridTemplateColumns: Math.max(100+'px', 50+'px') Math.max(100+'px', 50+'px') Math.max(100+'px', 50+'px'),
```

I also tried to use some fancy [] and {} here and there, but I did not manage them correctly.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using `Math.max` with constant values? `Math.max(65, 200)` will never result in anything other than `200`.

Comment: My preferred way: `[Math.max(100, 50), Math.max(100, 50), Math.max(100, 50)].map(n => n + 'px').join(' ')`

Comment: I am not using Math.max(65,200), I just used it for simplifying the question. I am using a scale factor something like this: Math.max(800, scale / 8). Now it works. I was missing this: `$

Comment: You're using [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String) already but I suspect you don't know what it means.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @user13319165! You may get more answers if the title of your post is asked as a question like “How do I add 3 values with JavaScript and set them as a CSS value?”  Also, if you are new to learning CSS or JavaScript, tell us so we can point you to helpful resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation syntax

```
const obj = {
    gridTemplateColumns: `${Math.max(100, 50)}px ${Math.max(100, 50)}px ${Math.max(100, 
    50)}px` 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're so close!

go with

```
gridTemplateColumns: Math.max(100, 50) + 'px ' + Math.max(100, 50) + 'px ' + Math.max(100, 50) + 'px'
```

you'll probably benefit from making a function to do this:

```
function maxPx(a,b) {
 return Math.max(a,b) + 'px'
}
```

but then you need to make sure not to forget to put spaces between values:

```
gridTemplateColumns: maxPx(100, 50) + ' ' + maxPx(100, 50) + ' ' + maxPx(100, 50)
```

or

```
gridTemplateColumns: [maxPx(100, 50), maxPx(100, 50), maxPx(100, 50)].join(' ')
```